# WatchKit Animation not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I Have added some images to the asset catalogue for the watch kit. I can set the image that is displayed, but whenever I try to animate the image, the image just disappears.

Even if I try to code this, the exact same things happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some the code you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, for the delay. I couldn't figure this out, but if I created a new view in storyboard and added the same code, then it worked.